# Install/Use NpgSQL on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-2010, npgsql

I'm trying to connect to a Postgres 9.5 database using VB.NET/VS2010. I've got the 4.5 .NET framework installed and the project is targeting ".NET Framework 4". I used Npgsql-3.2.5.msi to install the NpgSQL.dll and referenced the dll, but was unable to build the project, or see any of the NpgSQL objects in the intellisense. I had tried using NuGet for the current version, but it threw errors when i tried to install it. I used

```
"Install-Package Npgsql -Version 3.2.5"
```

I did some research and was able to install the NuGet Legacy package

```
"Install-Package Npgsql.EntityFrameworkLegacy -Version 2.2.7"
```

but the project still refuses to build and I'm still unable to access the Npgsql objects, at least in the intellisense. When I try to build I get 
"Could not load file or assembly 'PostGreSQL Test.exe' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded." as an error.

Any help in getting a version of Npgsql to work with Visual Studio 2010 would be greatly appreciated! or at least let me know if it's not possible. This will be a read only connection.

here's the chunk of sample code i'm starting with:

```
Private Sub GetData()

    Using conn = New Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection(connectionString)

        conn.Open()

        ' Retrieve all rows
        Using cmd = New Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand("SELECT some_field FROM data", conn)

            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

                While reader.Read()
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0))
                End While

            End Using 'reader

        End Using 'cmd

    End Using 'conn

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you really have a good reason for using such an ancient version of Visual Studio? Do you know whether you need Npgsql (the SQL-level driver) or Entity Framework (the ORM)? These are two very different things. Npgsql 2.x is extremely old and unmaintained, and it is a bad idea to use it in a new app.

Comment: I'm stuck with VS2010 for now, and I'd like to stick with Npgsql just so the code's consistent. The app uses MSSQL and i just need to do a few reads from a Postgre database.